# Key value stores

Tags: bigdata, databases, nosql

I am writing an essay & I couldn't find a clear answer, I am new to this concept. Do key-value stores have specific attributes? What are they? I need a source for further understanding if possible.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question is not related to Data Science. However, have you tried entering this into a search engine?